AABB Collision Resolution Per Face
I have this function that detect the collision of two AABBs:
struct CollisionResult {
    bool collision;
};


static struct CollisionResult player_collision(ivec3 position) {
    struct CollisionResult result;

    vec3 aMin, aMax;
    vec3 bMin, bMax;

    glm_vec3_copy(player.position, aMin);
    glm_vec3_copy((vec3){
        player.position[0] + player.dimensions[0],
        player.position[1] + player.dimensions[1],
        player.position[2] + player.dimensions[2],
    }, aMax);

    glm_vec3_copy((vec3){
        position[0] - 0.5,
        position[1] - 0.5,
        position[2] - 0.5
    }, bMin);

    glm_vec3_copy((vec3){
        position[0] + 1.0 - 0.5,
        position[1] + 1.0 - 0.5,
        position[2] + 1.0 - 0.5
    }, bMax);

    result.collision = (
        aMin[0] <= bMax[0] &&
        aMax[0] >= bMin[0] &&
        aMin[1] <= bMax[1] &&
        aMax[1] >= bMin[1] &&
        aMin[2] <= bMax[2] &&
        aMax[2] >= bMin[2]
    );

    return result;
}

And as for responding to that collision for say, the Y axis, it would look like this, which works fine:
    int axis = 1; // Y axis
    struct CollisionResult result = player_collision(blockCollisionPosition);
    if (sign(camera.motion[axis]) < 0) {
        camera.position[axis] = blockCollisionPosition[axis] - 0.5 + 1.0 + 0.001;
    } else {
        camera.position[axis] = blockCollisionPosition[axis] - 0.5 - 1.0 - 0.001;
    }

However, this only works on a per axis basis. I'm trying to detect the normal, or face hit of each AABB but I couldn't figure out a solution. Currently, if I loop through all 3 axes (x, y, z) the collision response code doesn't work obviously since it just sets the position of all 3 axes even if the player's not collding with that normal or axis itself.
Does anyone have any insight on how to finish this simple collision response? Is setting the position like this even the correct way of responding to the collision?

Have you considered using an existing physics engine to detect and handle collisions?

I don't know why everyone comments something like this; yes I've considered it and I wouldn't be asking this if I planned to use an existing physics engine.

I asked because we get developers of all experience levels here, and some beginners do not realize that libraries and tools exist to make their lives easier, or don't realize how long it might take to reinvent the wheel.

Your question is confusing because you talk about "responding" to the collision, but don't clearly state what kind of situation you are responding to or what kind of response you want. It looks like you are moving the camera when the player collides with a block, but why? What kind of response are you looking for?

"...it just sets the position of all 3 axes even if the player's not collding with that normal or axis itself." I can't see any part of your code checking if (result.collision) {...} before moving the camera, are you taking care of this somewhere else?
